# Archaeology and תחיית המתים

Tags: history, messiah, science, nevua-prophecy, archaeology

A few minutes ago, while standing in the rain and seeing some people passing out some pamphlets an idea occurred to me.

Are there any papers, books, dvar torahs etc, which links the traditional concept of תחיית המתים (Resurrection of the dead), a reference to the "Dry Bones" of ezekiel, and 
the modern [advances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Archaeology_Review) of [archaeology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_archaeology), and particularly, [old](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.foxnews.com/scitech/2011/12/27/ancient-seal-found-in-jerusalem-linked-to-ritual/&ei=jUEYT8b3BdP18QPe4OCmCw&usg=AFQjCNFfEuy0dTjBPm1iQ97ziotrR__Cbg) [Jewish](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/History/Genizah.html) [texts](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/f-chat/2827156/posts) and artifacts which are preserved well by dry weather?

*edit
Another random though, is the concept of Techeyet Hamaytim and the feeling one gets when reading the words of a lost author, or an author in general, and how this might relate to archaeology and lost texts.

*Fun side note: To get the hebrew words in the title I had to type "Dead revival" in google translate.. Now I feel like going to a concert.*

Comment: From the title I thought this question was going to be about the disruptive effects of archaeological digs (e.g. disrupting graves) on resurrection.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Man plans and Gd laughs :)

Comment: Huh? What does archaeology have to do with תחיית המתים ?

Comment: @ArielK I'm not sure what you are asking exactly, but think metaphorically rather than literally.

Comment: If you mean to re-interpret techiyas hamesim to just mean "finding old texts" that would be outside traditional Judaism and against the Mishnah in Sanhedrin. If you just mean it as an additional aspect, fine, but I don't really see the connection.

Comment: Though some interpret the "dry bones" in Ezekiel as a metaphor for the Jewish People, not an actual event. Also, R.Y.M. Lau cited it in reference to the rebirth of the Jewish people in Israel after the holocaust.

Comment: @ArielK I'm sorry you don't see the connection. However the five people I've mentioned it to today, all said that it was quite interesting and/or a cute drash. My question is if anyone has written on it before.  I'm not sure why you seem to be offended at the suggestion.

Comment: @ArielK, If I'm understanding things correctly here, what avi is asking is if anyone uses the concept of "techiyas hameisim" to describe the "resurrection" of old texts and artifacts, and maybe even draws parallels between the two occurrences. I highly doubt that avi is trying to undermine the veracity of one of Rambam's 13 principles.

Comment: OK, but whether someone else says it isn't a very significant question. Though I guess there isn't another way to share "a cute drash" on this site...

Comment: @ArielK If someone else has said it, and written a thorough exploration of the topic, is very much a significant question.  If nobody has, then it gives me a project.

Comment: Do you mean something like דאמר ר' יוחנן משום ר' שמעון בן יוחי: כל תלמיד חכם שאומרים דבר שמועה מפיו בעולם הזה שפתותיו דובבות בקבר from Bechorot 31b?

Comment: @DoubleAA, That would depend what you think that line means/is saying.  But Shadal so far is the closest thing I've seen to what I was asking.

Comment: Sorry Avi, but I haven't the foggiest idea what you're even asking.

Comment: @SethJ I find that odd, since Shadal writes what I was looking for.  An application of "resurection of the dead" as applied to ideas or texts instead of people.  The fact that texts are preserved by dry weather, and a reference to "dry bones" was a possible direction the analogy could have gone. (but it doesn't) as I think, after some searching, that Shadal was the only one to mention this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a direct match, [Shadal did make a similar statement](http://onthemainline.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/shadal-series-3-on-important-role.html) regarding the printing of old manuscripts.

> "God sees how topsy-turvy the present (=mid-19th century) is and he
>   acts for the good of his creation, knowing that each generation needs
>   its teachers and judges. To understand how God acts, think of a king
>   who rules over a vast empire. When he sees that his subjects in the
>   farthest reaches lack proper supervision, he sends them leaders and
>   judges from other provinces. So it is that God saw that the generation
>   is orphaned, with many following nothing and nonsense. Even the sages
>   and wise men are ineffective as leaders. So what does God do? He sends
>   them sages and leaders from another generation. He causes old books to
>   be lifted out of the dust piles, in order that their voices can be
>   heard in a later generation. **It is as if he returns the soul to the
>   dead, breathing new life into the hearts of those that are straying.
>   He turns the heart of the fathers - already dead - to the children,** in
>   order to turn the heart of the children toward their fathers. This is
>   just in time before it's too late and the generation all goes to
>   waste."